# Problem with exoplayer: can't play stream in android 9 and above

Tags: audio, error-handling, video-streaming, exoplayer, exoplayer-media-item

I am making online radio streaming, for a local radio station.
Unfortunately, the stream works ok with android version 8 and below, but it fails in android version 9 and above.

here is my code so far (for the play function)

```
 player = new ExoPlayer.Builder(this).build();
        MediaItem mediaItem  = new MediaItem.Builder()
                .setUri("http://stream.zeno.fm/fiit4u4ied0uv")
                        .build();

        player.setMediaItem(mediaItem);
        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
        playerView.setPlayer(player);
        player.prepare();
```

along with internet permission i have these as well in manifest

```
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

here is network_security_config code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
        <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
            <domain includeSubdomains="true">http://stream.zeno.fm</domain>
        </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

my stream url is: http://stream.zeno.fm/fiit4u4ied0uv

i have been strugling with this for three days.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted this line in manifest

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

The use of network_security_config didn't work
The two should not work together as well.